# Grunt-jade, express.js and i18n

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, gruntjs

I use Grunt, Jade and express.js.

In my jade template i Use i18n  - https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/

like this:

```
span #{__('Agencja')}
```

When i start grunt serve it is ok, it works excellent.
But if i want to compile it grunt-jade tell me that

```
> span #{__('Agencja')}
undefined is not a function
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'm looking for a response too, did you find how to allow Jade to compile with i18n ? Thks

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2

then in your jade templates use:

```
span= __('Text')
```

or

```
span #{__("Text")}
```